Drake method not working within ROS2 control update loop
While building a ROS2 control controller class (that implements ControllerInterface), I have notices that calling the Drake method CalcJacobianTranslationalVelocity within the update function triggers the error below when a command is published to the topic.
Command that triggers error

ros2 topic pub /my_ik_controller/commands
std_msgs/msg/Float64MultiArray "data:

0.5
0.5"


ERROR

[ERROR] [ros2_control_node-2]: process has died [pid 10489, exit code
-11, cmd '/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node --ros-args --params-file /home/name/Documents/ros2_projects/drawing_robot_ws/install/base_package/share/base_package/config/ik_controller.yaml
--params-file /tmp/launch_params_wjnehmxb'].

However, the exact same isolated code works fine if...

it is placed in a separate .cpp program
it is placed within the .on_init() method of the controller
the equivalent pydrake/python code also works.

Here is the relevant code.
  // -----------BELOW NORMALLY WITHIN ROS2 CONTROLLER HEADER------------
  private:
    MultibodyPlant<double> _plant;
    std::unique_ptr<Context<double>> _plantContextPointer;


  // -----------BELOW NORMALLY WITHIN ROS2 CONTROLLER CONSTRUCTOR------------
  DifferentialInverseKinematicsCalculator::DifferentialInverseKinematicsCalculator()
    :_plant (0.0) // time step 0.0 for continuous system
  {
  }


  // -----------BELOW NORMALLY WITHIN ROS2 CONTROLLER ON_INIT()------------
  const std::string& urdf = get_robot_description();
  Parser parser(&_plant);
  parser.AddModelsFromString(urdf, ".urdf");
  const auto& basebody = _plant.GetBodyByName("base_link");
  _plant.WeldFrames(_plant.world_frame(), basebody.body_frame(), RigidTransformd());
  _plant.Finalize();
  auto _plantContextPointer = _plant.CreateDefaultContext();


  // -----------BELOW NORMALLY WITHIN ROS2 CONTROLLER UPDATE()------------
  Eigen::Matrix3Xd jacobian(3, _plant.num_positions()); // if spatial velocity, includes rotation, so 6, not 3.
  Eigen::Vector3d p_BoBp_B;
  p_BoBp_B << 0.0,0.0,0.0;
  const Frame<double>& _endFrame = _plant.GetBodyByName("end_effector").body_frame();
  const Frame<double>& _worldFrame = _plant.world_frame();
  _plant.CalcJacobianTranslationalVelocity(
      *_plantContextPointer, drake::multibody::JacobianWrtVariable::kV, _endFrame, p_BoBp_B, _worldFrame, _worldFrame, &jacobian);

The error will not be thrown if the final line, _plant.CalcJacobian... is commented out.
Any ideas what might be causing this? Is it something to do with the realtime loop of the update method?

Probably there is not enough information here for us to help you. My only question/guess... is there a chance you are updating the context in another thread in a way that is not thread-safe with this call?

Thank you for the response. It was a silly mistake, still new to C++. I used GDB to try and figure out the problem with my plant context. Realized that within the on_init function, running gdb's info locals listed _plantContextPointer, because I had put auto in front of it's initialization, so it wasn't assigning a value to the private member variable, but to a local variable.

Sorry for the simple mistake. Happy to delete this question since the error doesn't relate to drake specifically.
